# Is this scenario possible in c# method inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to know if this scenario is possible in C# inheritance.

Let's assume we have 3 classes.

```
public class Base
{   
    public abstract void SomeMethod(Base param);
}

public class ChildA : Base
{   
    public override void SomeMethod(ChildA param);
}

public class ChildB : Base
{   
    public override void SomeMethod(ChildB param);
}
```

I do not want to typecast the base param everytime in the child class method. So, is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That feature is called formal parameter type covariance. It is not supported by c#. Also it is not typesafe.

Two variations on it are typesafe. Formal parameter contravariance and return type covariance. C# does support those for generic delegate conversions and for method group to delegate conversions but does not support them for virtual method overriding.

You're out of luck here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

No. The parameters must be an exact match.

The whole purpose of virtual/override is that you will usually call the method from a Base class reference:

```
 Base b = ....;
 b.SomeMethod(x);  // might actually call ChildA.SomeMethod() or ChildB.SomeMethod()
```

Comment: The main reason I am accepting Eric's answer is because I learnt something new from the terms he used(formal covariance, contravariance, etc). Thanks so much for quickly answering this.